# Microsoft Player Framework not playing local files

Tags: windows, video, windows-8, winjs

I am developing a windows 8 app in winjs and one of its features is to be able to play local video files. So far I am using:

Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync

Which works fine but obviously suspends the app and opens the video with their default video program. I would rather keep the user in the app so I tried to implement it using the Microsoft Player Framework(http://playerframework.codeplex.com/). I know the framework is referenced correctly etc because it can play video files both in the 'app data' directory and online.

However when I try to play files within a folder that the user has picked (with the folder picker) or the videos library that the app has declared access to, the video fails to play. The app can however change the name, create new files in the directory and delete files so I struggle to see a permissions problem.

To get the path of the file I am using getFileAsync( and using the path property and simply using that to set the src property of the MediaPlayer control.

Do any windows 8 app gurus have any suggestions as to why it is not working?

Thanks in advance

p.s. let me know if any further info is required

Comment: Do you see any error messages or exceptions?

Comment: No exceptions of any kind, it just says 'Failed to play video' on the actual video element...

Comment: This happens for all video files picked through the picker? And they can be played with the normal video app?

Comment: I have it set up so that the user picks a folder containing the video file and the app looks inside that folder and plays the first video file it finds. At the moment they play fine when the app refers to the default video player on the machine i.e. VLC player for me. I wanted to get the video playing within the app.